# how to make webpack / react and electron work in secure context?

Tags: reactjs, security, webpack, electron

I have looked at tons of various posts but barely could find on how to make webpack work with electron in secure way.

A lot of devs suggest to enable **nodeIntegrations** and disable **contextIsolation**.
But this can lead to security flaws? [electron security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#checklist-security-recommendations)

I have used electron forge to build the project skeleton. I can run the electron app in dev mode. But when I try to package it

I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

How can this issue be solved without enabling **nodeIntegrations** and not disabling **contextIsolation**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project I had was built with electron forge.
I run in various different issues.

For me what fixed all issues was upgrading all packages with **yarn upgrade**.
Now the electron app created executable without issue and contextIsolation works as well.

If someone experience similar issue try to upgrade the packages.